# <script> does not able to load another js file in the page

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access this url via javascript to loaf a function in my js page:

[url which contains a function](https://oasc12.247realmedia.com/RealMedia/ads/adstream_mjx.ads)

Then I will easily call the function and load some info.

I have the following code:

```
document.write('<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=JavaScript SRC="https://oasc12.247realmedia.com/RealMedia/ads/adstream_mjx.ads"></SCRIPT>');
OAS_RICH('UNKNOWN');
```

and my html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

</head>
<body>
 <div id="mobile-ad">

    <div class="sidebox advertisement">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/test/ads.js"></script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now my problem when I run it I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: OAS_RICH is not defined" which means that the function loading does not work via

Can anyone help why it is not working ? Am I missing anything?

Comment: you'lll have to wait for that other script to load.

Comment: Dot use document.write.... Its dangerous. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: @DanielA.White but it is just a simple function. Does it take that long?

Comment: it can.........

Comment: Scripts are loaded async, how long it exactly takes doesn't matter. Even if it only takes 1ms, the OAS_RICH() call will always be scheduled before the script arrives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this:

```
<script id="adscript"></script>
<script>
var adScript = document.getElementById("adscript");
adScript.addEventListener("load", function () {
    OAS_RICH('UNKNOWN');
});
adScript.src = "https://oasc12.247realmedia.com/RealMedia/ads/adstream_mjx.ads";
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I just have  one issue with this method: when I want to load <a> and img in acontainer document.write remove everything from the page and just write a and img. Do have any suggestion for that?

Comment: Don't use `document.write()`, at all. If you want to add new elements somewhere, either append them to an existing element's contents using `insertBefore()` or set an element's `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 2):

why you are not putting your script balise directly in the head of the html page.
Then at the end of the body you add a script that call your function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <script src="https://oasc12.247realmedia.com/RealMedia/ads/adstream_mjx.ads"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mobile-ad">

      <div class="sidebox advertisement">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/test/ads.js"></script>
      </div>
      <script>
        OAS_RICH('UNKNOWN');
      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
```